# Possibility of choosing $ε$ as function of $x_{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

In the definition of the limit of sequence $(x_{n})$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence#Definition)

I know that the definition is for all $ε>0$.

Traditionally, the values of $ε$ are not depends on $n$.

If I choose $ε$ (I am speaking on a particular case from the case $ε>0$) as function of $x_{n}$, i.e., taking $ε=g(x_{n})$ for some real function $g$. The existence of $N$ is guaranteed by the fact that the sequence is convergent.

My **question** is: Can I find an $N$ for this particular case where $ε_{n}=g(x_{n})$ such that the inequality $|x_{n}-l|<g(x_{n})$ holds for all $n>N$.

Comment: Not following.  the limit requires something to hold $\textit {for all } \epsilon$, not just a single value.   Where would $n$ fit in?

Comment: @lulu: I am not asking for all values. I am asking on the possibility of choosing one of that form..

Comment: @Helena So given x_n, you want a function that returns epsilon. But what epsilon do you want to return? Do you want an epsilon such that there exists an N such that d(x_k,x) < epsilon for all k>=N where k>=n ?
If so, this is not a function, because the output of the function, epsilon, can take many values.

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity.  It is not at all clear what you are asking.

Comment: @lulu: Yes. I have edited the question.

Comment: Still not clear.  Since the definition of a limit refers to all $\epsilon >0$, you are free to choose a particular such $\epsilon $ if you like.  Is that what you are asking?  Of course, that's a lot weaker than the definition of a limit.  And it still isn't clear where $n$ fits in.

Comment: @lulu: Yes. this is exactly the question.

Comment: Well, I don't see the point, but you can just take $\epsilon = 1$ if you want.  The constant function.

Comment: @lulu: I required that it depends on $n$.

Comment: Constant functions are still functions.  But take $\epsilon(n)=\frac 1n$ if you'd rather.

Comment: Not intending to be mean here, but I feel like the question still isn't being asked clearly. This function epsilon thing is weird. OP, you should consider re-wording the question to make it crystal clear what you mean. Spend longer thinking about exactly what question you want to ask... For example, you need to either reference the definition  of convergent sequence in the link (for any epsilon...), or your question needs to *not* be related to the definition of convergent  sequence in the link (which I suspect is the case).

Comment: @AdamRubinson: The question is edited.

Comment: So g is *any* function, not at all related to the convergence of (x_n)? You haven't specified what the properties of the function g are.

Comment: @AdamRubinson: you can consider it strictly positive and bijective.

Comment: "The existence of N is guaranteed by the fact that the sequence is convergent." Are you talking about the sequence $\epsilon_n = g(x_n) $or the sequence $x_n$ here ?

Comment: @AdamRubinson: In the question I write the sequence $x_n$

Comment: You don't tell us much about the function g. $g(x_n)$ could be a divergent sequence, meaning the answer to your question, as it stands, is "no".

Comment: @AdamRubinson: So the condition that this sequence $g(x_{n})$ is **bounded** is required.

Comment: That's not good enough though. $g(x_n)$ could be bounded but divergent e.g. -1, 1, -1, 1, ... . Or, even if $g(x_n)$ converges, it could converge to some limit $m =/= l$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider any convergent sequence $(x_n)$ with limit $l$.

Let us suppose the sequence is not eventually constant (i.e. there is no $N$ such that i.e. $x_n=l$ for all $n\geq N$). Then if and only if $g(x_n)>0$ for all $n$, for all $n$ there is an $N$ such that $d(x_i,l) < g(x_i)$ for all $i \geq N$.

If the sequence if eventually constant then the inequality is relaxed to  $g(x_n)\geq 0$ for $n\geq N$, where $N$ is the point when the sequence becomes constant.

Comment: Your choice of epsilon wouldn't fit the *strict inequality* definition of convergence. epsilon would have to be just greater than sup{...} in order to guarantee the conditions of the definition are satisfied.

Comment: You're right. I think it should be easily fixed, though...

Comment: Yes that makes sense to me now. Although I suspect we have both misunderstood OP's actual question lol.

Comment: @AdamRubinson: Yes. the answer is not compatible with question.

Comment: So are you asking if the condition holds for $\epsilon$ chosen as any function of $x_n$? The answer is then clearly no, but for some functions it is clearly yes.

Comment: @broncoAbierto: Can you give a characterization of those functions.

Comment: @Helena I think it's a bit messy because of sequences that are eventually constant, but if you discard those, any strictly positive function works.

Comment: @Helena I think this should work. The wording could be improved, I guess...